# Jenkins RobotFramework plugin creates wrong URL for Log file

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

My project results are in D:\Projects\Robot\scratch\Results
and I can see them when clicking on the log.html or results.html.
I have put the full path and just 'Results' in the RobotFramework plugins 'Directory of Robot output' field.
But when run, the plugin gives me this URL:

http://localhost:8080/job/RFScratch/5/robot/report/log.html

Which goes nowhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the output directory outside of the jenkins workspace directory ?

Comment: Yes all the scripts and output are in the workspace directory.

Comment: if you switch `localhost:8080` to what your jenkins master is really accessible, does the url work then ?

Comment: Not quite following. The jenkins, and RF directory, are not setup as web sites. Should they be? And /RFScratch/5/robot/report is not a location in my file system.